# How does one open multiple tabs in TextWrangler?

Tags: macos, tabs, text-editors, textwrangler

No, I'm not bluffing. I really can't figure this out.

### The setup:

I went to `File -> Open`, and then selected a *directory* rather than a file. As expected, a directory tree opened on the left side of my document. Hooray! I can easily view the files' structure in my Rails project. So, I make a few changes in a file, and then I click on a different file in the directory tree.

### My problem:

TextWrangler then asks me whether I want to save my changes. Huh? I say "No", and the new document doesn't open at all. Great. I try hitting <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (new document). A new *window* opens. Ughhhh. How the heck do I open documents in a new tab?

Note: I have set the "New & opened documents" behavior to "Open in the front window". This does *not* change the behavior described (i.e. when a directory is opened rather than a single file).

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124014/textwrangler-open-file-in-new-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By selecting the directory you open a *DIsk Browser* (see window title).

When you create a new document, that document has no location on disk yet. But the Disk Browser window is associated with that folder. *It wouldn't make sense to place it in a list of files of a certain directory as long as it's unsaved and has no location.* In fact, it doesn't open in "in a new window", but in the window containing perhaps previously created unnamed documents.

Regarding editing, while [this](http://www.listsearch.com/TextWrangler/Thread/index.lasso?359#954) topic is a bit older and no longer accurate it highlights the limited capabilities of TextWrangler. While they implemented editing, it doesn't seem they implemented tabs/multiple opened modified documents for Disk Browser windows.

> > So my next question is whether there is a way to have multiple files
> >     open with the disk browser. I'm looking for an SFTP solution.
> >     ExpanDrive + BBEdit works great
>
> The disk browser is browser focused; 1 document at a time with quick 
>   editing as necessary.
>
> For working with multiple files, creating a Project will be a much 
>   better fit.
>
> Projects currently can support reference nodes to things in locally 
>   mountable file systems, and individual URL based items.

---

<sub>Get a real editor if you're working with it a lot, not the free companion to a commercial product. While I don't use BBEdit, I know that at least the multiple opened, modified documents are possible in TextMate.</sub>

Comment: +1 Do you know whether it's possible to open a "Project" in TextWrangler? I couldn't see any reference to "Projects" in the UI, and the following search turned up nothing: http://www.google.com/search?q=textwrangler+create+project

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: I know I should. ,_, I was trying to avoid paying $50 for a text editor, but I might have to go with TextMate. I might also go with MacVim + NERDtree.

Comment: @Closure Both the TextWrangler help and a menu item refer to "Project List", but I couldn't find anything either. If I'd have to guess, I'd say it's a feature no longer present, or the person I quoted is wrong in that regard. Since he was working for Barebones at the time, I say it's the former.

Comment: Ha! I missed that. Well, I suppose this is answered. Rats.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

1. TextWrangler Preferences
2. Documents & Drawer
3. New & Opened Documents
4. Select "Open in the Front Window"